# MongoDB Warning After Connection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have connected my mongodb atlas to my linux system.

[image]

Warning: Found ~/.mongorc.js, but not ~/.mongoshrc.js. ~/.mongorc.js will not be loaded.
You may want to copy or rename ~/.mongorc.js to ~/.mongoshrc.js.

But, I am getting this warning why?

And after that, I can't view any data in the same files.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text

Answer (score 1):

New [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/) reads `.mongoshrc.js` file at startup. Classic [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongo) shell reads the `.mongorc.js` file.

The message is about legacy/transition from classic to new mongosh.

My suggestion: Use the class `mongo` shell, the new `mongosh` is far away from being a usable successor of the classic shell, it still lacks many functions and has a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This warning message is ignorable. It happens when you have previously run the legacy mongo shell 13 (which creates a .mongorc.js in your home directory) and subsequently run the new MongoDB Shell (mongosh) 19 which looks for .mongoshrc.js instead.

Please visit this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/warning-found-mongorc-js-but-not-mongoshrc-js-mongorc-js-will-not-be-loaded/129716/3) where the issue was addressed by Stennie of MongoDB Community Team